# Wrong 1st Arguement type. Found 'String' , required Integer

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to put a json array into Recyclerview. When i did it with only one arguement (store_textposition) everything works fine but when i add another arguement (store_name) it gives me the `"Wrong 1st argument type. Found 'String' , required Integer"`.

This is my json array :

```
{"action":"true","error":"","data":[{"_id":"58ad8d8ca49d0e11e21c4504","store_name":"firstStore","store_view":0,"store_textposition":null}]}
```

and there is where i'm getting the error :

```
 private boolean parse()
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray ja = obj.getJSONArray("data");
        JSONObject jo;
        shops.clear();
        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String store_name = jo.getString("store_name");
            String store_textposition = jo.getString("store_textposition");
            shops.add(store_textposition,store_name);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is unclear here? The error explicitly says that the first argument needs to be an integer, but yours is a String.

Comment: What type has `shops` object?

Comment: I'm going to assume `shops` is a `List<String>`. I'm also going to assume you're trying to add two Strings in the list. The proper way to do it is by calling add() twice, each time for each String. The compiler thinks you're trying to use the method add(index, item) which adds the the String item to a specified index.

Comment: @AlinPandichi i tried it but it shows each arguemnt in diffrent recyclreviews

Comment: shops is your model class?

Answer (score 0):

as @AlinPandichi mentioned in comments, your problem is when you are adding objects to shop list.

I do not know what you want to do exactly. But, if `store_textposition` is an int, you better use

> int store_textposition = jo.optInt("store_textposition");

This way, even the server pass yo null you have default value of 0 which prevent your app from crashing.

I think it will solve your problem.